# What are the differences between features and components?

Tags: terminology, standards, features, component

My boss asked me to change a software installation. He wants to change the word **features** to **components**. I'm not sure about the meaning of this change. I've gone ahead and implemented this at his request.

From the merriam-webster.com:

**components** : one of the parts that make up a whole

**features** : something that sets apart an individual from others of the same kind

So in software GUI design, when do we use the term **components**, instead of **features**?

Is there any standard about how to use these terms in the context of software, similar to this issue?

e.g.

```
Select the features for "My software" you would like to install:
  -Package 1
    -Service 1
    -Service 2
    -Service 3
  -Package 2
    -Service 4
    -Service 5
    -Service 6
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand this question. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @Mervin : I'm sorry. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *component* is **a tool**, in this case it's a piece of software. Many components and their relationships make **a system**.

A *feature* is some **functionality**, that is what the tool **does**.

E.g., "My system has a *share-to* **component**; it's written in `python`. Its **features** include *sharing* to `personbook` and `whistler`."

Typically, you can install a component, as it's a piece of software, but you cannot install a feature, as it's something that software does.

Answer (score 1):

If Mr. X asks about an object Y,

- What Y is made of --> its components ...
- What Y can do  --> its features ...

For example, take **Microsoft Office**,

**Components:**

- Microsoft Word
- again, it's components:

- spell-checker,
- Page designer,
- Word art etc.

- Excel
- it's components:

- formula editor,
- Graph editor,
- Diagram etc.

**But, features ?**

- Microsoft Word

- can detect your spelling mistake
- you can customize page-design
- you can draw simple arts etc.

- Microsoft Excel

- can detect your formula mistake
- you can customize the overall sheet design
- you can create charts from your data etc.